# Как сделать что бы меню в мобильной версии закрывалось при клике на пункте из меню?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать, чтобы в мобильной версии, при выборе пункта меню, меню автоматически сворачивалось.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#section-1" class="page-scroll">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section-2" class="page-scroll">Section 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section-3" class="page-scroll">Section 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
    <script>
    $(document).on('click', 'a.page-scroll', function(event) {
  var $anchor = $(this);
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 50
  }, 800, 'easeInOutExpo');
  event.preventDefault();
});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Должно помочь

```
$('.navbar-nav a').on('click', function(){ 
        if($('.navbar-toggle').css('display') !='none'){
            $(".navbar-toggle").trigger( "click" );
        }
 });
```

Пример

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a.page-scroll', function(event) {
  var $anchor = $(this);
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 50
  }, 800, 'easeInOutExpo');
  event.preventDefault();
});


$('.navbar-nav a').on('click', function() {
  if ($('.navbar-toggle').css('display') != 'none') {
    $(".navbar-toggle").trigger("click");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

section:before {
  content: 'section';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

section:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: red;
}

section:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Static navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#section-1" class="page-scroll">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section-2" class="page-scroll">Section 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section-3" class="page-scroll">Section 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<section id="section-1"></section>
<section id="section-2"></section>
<section id="section-3"></section>
```